# how to send styles with html email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am using PHP `mail()` function to send the email. I have a table in the email with specific styles, but when I receeve the email, it does not show me the images and all style is disturbed.

My code is below:

```
    $recipient = $_POST['Users']['email'];
    $name   =   $_POST['Users']['first_name'];
    $username   =   $_POST['Users']['username'];
    $password   =   $_SESSION['password'];

    $referrer_name     =    $model->referrer = $referrer_data['first_name'];
    $referrer_email     =    $model->referrer = $referrer_data['email'];
    // print_r($referrer_name);
    // print_r($referrer_email);

    $webstore   =   $this->base_url . "/" . Yii::app()->session['username']; 
    $headers    = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $subject    = "Sign Up- Success";
    $message = "<table width='700' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='bordermain'>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'><table width='666' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
        <td width='666' colspan='2' align='center' valign='top'><table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
          <tr>
            <td width='50%' align='left' valign='middle'><img src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/karmora-websiteLogo.png' width='175' height='50'  alt=''/></td>
            <td width='50%' align='right' valign='middle'><table width='120' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
              <tr>
                <td width='30' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='http://www.facebook.com/' target='_blank'><img src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/facebook.jpg'  alt='Facebook' width='25' height='25' title='Facebook'/></a></td>
                <td width='30' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='http://www.twitter.com/' target='_blank'><img src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/twitter.jpg'  alt='Twitter' width='25' height='25' title='Twitter'/></a></td>
                <td width='30' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/' target='_blank'><img src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/pintrest.jpg'  alt='Pinterest' width='25' height='25' title='Pinterest'/></a></td>
                <td width='30' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/' target='_blank'><img border='0' width='25' height='25' src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/youtube.jpg' alt='YouTube'/></a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='left' valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='center' valign='top'><table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
          <tr>
            <td align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#f9f9f9' style='border:1px solid #CCC;'><table width='99%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
              <tr>
                <td><span class='mainheading'><strong>Congratulations</strong></span></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='center' valign='top' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
          <tr>
            <td height='20' align='center' valign='middle'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align='center' valign='middle' class='bodytext'><table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' style='border-top:2px solid #FF7D0F'>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align='left' valign='middle' class='bodytext'><p class='headingpink'><strong>Dear '$name'</strong></p>
                  <p>Congratulations  on your decision to become the newest member of <strong>'$referrer_name' </strong>Karmora Community!</p>
                  <p>Below you will  find important information about your new Karmora Webstore. Please print or save this email in a safe  location for future reference.</p>
                  <table width='400' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
                    <tr>
                      <td width='144'><strong><span class='bodytext'>Karmora  URL</span></strong></td>
                      <td width='256'><strong><span class='bodytext'><a href='#'>'$webstore'</a></span></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong><span class='bodytext'>User  Name</span></strong></td>
                      <td><strong><span class='bodytext'>'$username'</span></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong><span class='bodytext'>Password</span></strong></td>
                      <td><strong><span class='bodytext'>'$password'</span></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <p>Now  it's time for you to start building your own personal Karmora Community where  you can make money off the memberships and purchases of your Community  members!  Let&rsquo;s get this party started!</p>
                  <p class='headingpink'><strong>7 BABY STEPS TO GOOD KARMORA&#8482;:</strong></p>
                  <ol>
                    <li>Click on your Karmora URL and log in to your  back office to customize your Webstore. You will see 'Log In' in the upper right hand corner of your Webstore.</li>
                    <li>Click on the Profile button and upload your  picture while in the profile section. We  recommend recent pictures. Your  customers will want to know that it is your Webstore!</li>
                    <li>Go to the Training Section and watch the  Instructional Videos. You will find all  kinds of information to help you with your Karmora Webstore. </li>
                    <li>Click on the eWallet button and create your  eWallet. Instructions on how to do this  are found in the Training Section of your back office.</li>
                    <li>Use Go Daddy to secure a domain name for your  new Webstore and point the new domain to your Karmora Webstore URL above. Instructions on how to do this are found in  the Training Section of your back office </li>
                    <li>Make your first official Karmora purchase.</li>
                    <li>Start sharing your new Webstore with everyone  you speak to so they can begin a Karmora Community of their own. Once you have five active members in your  Karmora Community your Webstore is basically FREE!</li>
                  </ol>
                  <p>If you have  any questions please don&rsquo;t hesitate to contact <strong>'$referrer_name' </strong>by email at <a href='mailto:$referrer_email'>'$referrer_email'</a> or simply <u><a href='http://karmora.com/liveSupport'>click here</a></u> to chat with a  Good Karmora&#8482; Specialist seven days a week from 7am to 7pm Pacific Time. </p>
                  <p>As always we  wish you Good Luck, Good Fortune and Good Karmora&#8482;! </p>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align='left' valign='middle' style='border-bottom:2px solid #FF7D0F'>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align='center' valign='middle' class='bodytext'>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width='50%' height='70' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#000000' class='footertextwhite' style='border-top:2px solid #de3277; border-bottom: 2px solid #de3277'><table width='90%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
          <tr>
            <td height='40' align='left' valign='middle'><a href='http://karmora.com/contact' class='a1'>Contact Us<br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td width='50%' height='70' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#000000' class='footertextwhite' style='border-top:2px solid #de3277; border-bottom: 2px solid #de3277'><table width='90%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
          <tr>
            <td height='40' align='right' valign='middle'><a href='http://www.karmora.com/liveSupport/'><img src='".$this->theme_baseurl."/images/live_support_icon_03.png' width='110' height='32' /></a><br />
              <span class='footertext'>&copy; 2013 Karmora</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='center' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>";


        mail($recipient, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Comment: Remove the "\r\n"; when assigning $headers. A single header doesn't need a separator.

Comment: No. Quite likely NO, you should remove it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your styles inline in your elements

```
<p style="color:#000">...</p>
```

And you should use the PHP header

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

Comment: well any other way ? what if I dont want to put inline styles?

Comment: You can't, there is no way to send a stylesheet with an email

Comment: ok and waht about images? it is not showing images in email, after i click on download images

Comment: All images have to be absolute paths; With html emails, it's best to do everything in a table and pretend its' 1997 as best I'm aware as the email programs don't/can't handle html in as sophisticated a manner as current browsers do.

Comment: Have you tried the second header? Sometimes it's needed to complete the HTML mail

Comment: yes, second header aslo did not solve the problem, now giving the inline styles, but what about images? images already have absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use css other than inline and you are best advised to use table based layouts is that some if not most of the email clients such as outlook for example have VERY VERY old version of the browser embeded in them to show an html email.

So unfortunately all email has to be created like we were back in the days of IE6 or before.

As to your images not showing that is because you have to remember when the email is being read it is not a page on your website, so any images must have a fully defined domain and path like `src="http://www.yoursite.net/images/facebook.jpg`

Comment: Good info here, but slight amendment - inlining CSS is is for Gmail, not Outlook.

Comment: Newer versions of Outlook do not even use old IE engines. They're using Microsoft Word's rendering engine.

Comment: Not everyone uses Outlook. http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails/